# mongodb - Processing logical rules with mapreduce?

Tags: mongodb, logic, mapreduce, rules

Let's say I have these three rules:

```
[{ 
    selector: {_id: "1"},
    value: {name: "apple"} 
},
{ 
    selector: {name: "apple"},
    value: {type: "fruit"} 
},
{ 
    selector: {type: "fruit"},
    value: {class: "food"} 
}]
```

I would like to end up with this result:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    value: {
        name: "apple",
        type: "fruit",
        class: "food"
    }
}
```

Could I do this with mapreduce?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that with reduce.

Comment: that looks like a join, is that what you're trying to do? mongodb is built around the idea of storing denormalized data, so you may be arranging your data the wrong way...

Comment: A join could work in this case, but I'm interested in generating a list of objects from an arbitrarily long and complex list of rules. This is a gross simplification of a more complex use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the problem (node.js with mongodb driver). I'm pretty sure it could be optimized quite a bit.

```js
var logicize = function(db, callback) {
    var reduce = function(key, values){
        // If values is an array of objects, it is merged into a single object
        if(values.length) {
            while(values.length>1) {
                var current = values.pop();
                for (var property in current) {
                    values[0][property] = current[property];
                }
            }
            return values[0];
        }
        return values;
    };

    db.collection("rules", function(err, rules) {
        db.collection("results", function(err, results) {
            rules.mapReduce("function() {emit(this.selector._id, this.value);}", reduce, {out: {replace:"results"}, query:{"selector._id":{$exists:true}}}, function() {
                rules.find({"selector._id":{$exists:false}}, function(err, cursor) {            
                    cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) { 
                        // Recursive because I don't want to start a new mapreduce 
                        // before the previous one has finished. The following one 
                        // might depend on the results of the previous
                        (function recurse(item) {
                            if(item==null) // Done
                                callback();
                            else {
                                var map = new Function('emit(this._id, '+JSON.stringify(item.value)+');');

                                var conditions = {};
                                for(var condition in item.selector) {
                                    conditions['value.'+condition] = item.selector[condition];
                                }
                                results.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{reduce:"results"},query: conditions}, function() { 
                                    // Previous mapreduce has finished so we can start the next one
                                    cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) {
                                        recurse(item);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        })(item);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Rules are in the "rules" collection and the results go into "results". I'm first performing an initial mapreduce with just the rules which have an _id. After that, I'm running a separate mapreduce for each of the other rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can pretty much do anything you want with mapreduce since you can execute arbitrary javascript on all your objects. But then you should be aware that mapreduce is not very fast for now, and it is advised not to do "db" operations within map/reduce functions (becomes inconsistent with sharding and can create locking issues).

Ideally the 1st step is to try to model the data so that it is pre-filled, even if that means duplicating some of the data. If that is not possible you should compare the speeds of mapreduce vs doing the work client side.